# Null Pointer exception to add blob to list of blob

Tags: class, list, pagereference, blob, blob.topdf

I have below piece of code where I am getting a Null pointer exception adding blob to a list of blobs. Can someone let me know my mistake please?

**Apex code**

```
counter=1;
form = integer.valueof(formquantity);
while (counter>0 && form>0) {
    System.debug(counter);
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/FormTemplatePrinter?id=a4VM0000000HtpOMAS&param1='+formquantity);
    pageRef.setRedirect(false);
    blob b1 = pageRef.getContent();
    b.add(b1);
    form-=5;
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Probably Some more details will help to solve this like about what line you are getting error at and  where is b defined. Is it initialized?

Comment: May be you are adding **b1** into **b** list without initializing the list.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on initialazing.

```
 public List<Blob> b = new List<Blob>();
```